# Redundant definitions involving ASL class and the mathtools package

Tags: document-classes, mathtools

The following minimal (non-)working example illustrates a clash between the Association of Symbolic Logic class file `asl.cls` (link [here](http://aslonline.org/files/AuthorResourcesTEX-files/asl.cls)) and `mathtools` package (both somewhat derived from AMS LaTeX):

```
\documentclass[jsl]{asl}
\usepackage{mathtools} % amsmath improvement

\DeclareMathOperator{\baphomet}{BAPHOMET}

\begin{document}

Hello $\baphomet(x)$.

\end{document}
```

I get a lot (83)

```
Command *** already defined
```

error messages, which disappear when I do not invoke the `mathtools` package. Is there a way to tell either `asl` or `mathtools` to ignore the redundant definitions?

Comment: asl.cls not in texlive, link to the class?

Comment: I assume this? https://aslonline.org/files/asl.cls  note this is a journal class that explicitly disables loading of ams classes. Technically you could disable these tests and load amsmath and mathtools, but then the document would probably not be acceptable to the journal.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, now included in the text.

Comment: with that class file I get `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \delimiter `  and latex never gets as far as the `mathtools` on line 2, does the class work at all for you?

Comment: oh, it works in texlive 2018 but it's completely unusable in  texlive 2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the document is being submitted to the journal then it is almost certainly best not to redefine anything, the class file intentionally disables AMS packages, after defining modified versions of that code.

However in old latex releases it probably works to do

```
\documentclass[jsl]{asl}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@amsmath.sty\endcsname{2019/01/01}
\expandafter\def\csname aligned@a\endcsname{}
\usepackage{mathtools} % amsmath improvement

\DeclareMathOperator{\baphomet}{BAPHOMET}

\begin{document}

Hello $\baphomet(x)$.

\end{document}
```

However in the 2019 release the class doesn't work at all as it needs to be updated to work with robust definitions. (or better updated to use amsmath rather than use a modified version of an ancient release)